# process of creating xenforo addon api

Tags: php, mysql, api, xenforo

I have a blog site in xenforo and am using an article management system addon it is working for end-user and admin also but am not understand how to create API for the same AMS Addon.
And please help with route creating for the same.

I am new for xenforo so please help of me the process of creating addons API.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The first step to learning how to developing for Xenforo would be to follow the Xenforo Dev Documentation [tutorial](https://xenforo.com/xf2-docs/dev/lets-build-an-add-on/) on how to build an addon.

Once you're accustomed to that you can read the documentation on the their REST API [here](https://xenforo.com/xf2-docs/dev/rest-api/) and [here](https://xenforo.com/community/pages/api-endpoints/)